package for swift, cannot find x in scope
I followed a few guides online showing how to create a package for swift, I created a repo at our gitlab and added the tags so I could import it properly into other projects, all that seemed to work great, but now in my project I have imported the library into, I am getting errors in Xcode any time I try to use my library... "Cannot find 'ChartData' in scope"
A quick example of this would be in "MyLibrary" I have the following "Package"
import PackageDescription
let package = Package(
  name: "MyLibrary",
  platforms: [.iOS(.v16), .macOS(.v14)],
  products: [
    .library(
      name: "MyLibrary",
      targets: ["MyLibrary"])
  ],
  targets: [
    .target(name: "MyLibrary", path: "Sources"),
    .testTarget(name: "MyLibraryTests", dependencies: ["MyLibrary"])
  ]
)

Simple, then I have in the "Sources" folder...

Sources

charts

ChartData.swift


MyLibrary.swift



Contents of ChartData.swift...
import Foundation
public class ChartData: Identifiable {
  public val id: String = UUID().uuidString
  public var amount: Int16
  public var timestamp: Date

  public init(amount: Int16, timestamp: Date) {
    self.amount = amount
    self.timestamp = timestamp
  }
}

Nice and simple. I then commit this all in git, add a tag (say 1.0.0) then push to my git repo with the tag.
In my working project I add a package dependency using my git url and password and all that good stuff, and I see the project has been added properly in Xcode because I can see it in "Package Dependencies" at the bottom of the file viewer.
So I create a new swift ui view and attempt to use ChartData
import SwiftUI
import MyLibrary
import Charts

struct ChartView: View {
  let data = ChartData(amount: Int16(2300), timestamp: Date())
  var body: some View {
    HStack { 
    }
  }
}

And right there on let data = ... I get the error Cannot find 'ChartData' in scope
I have tried changing my Package in the MyLibrary to be something a little more exact?
targets: [
  .target(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    resources: [
      .process("charts")
    ]
  )
  ...
]

but that doesn't work either. Not sure why my project can't seem to find ChartData in scope, since I am importing MyLibrary and it is defined and imported along with MyLibrary
Sorry if this is an obvious mistake on my part, I am just learning this and the only examples I could find of building a library literally had 1 file with some static code in it.
Thank you, and sorry for the long read.

Select the project file, select the app target, switch to Build Phases, and look under Link Binary With Libraries. Do you see your package, represented as a library? If not, that would be the problem.
